# How I can use onListItem to start a new activity with the ListView Value?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-activity, simplecursoradapter

Hi I have a android application and i use a sqlite database and a listview in my Activity. 
Now I want to use onListItemClick but I don_t know how I can get the value that I click and open a new activity with this value :(

here my code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

        mHelper = new DatenbankManager(this);
        mDatenbank = mHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 

        ladeDaten(); 

    }
```

my ladeDaten method:

```
  private void ladeDaten() {
        Cursor KlassenCursor = mDatenbank.rawQuery(KLASSEN_SELECT_ROW, null); 
        startManagingCursor(KlassenCursor); 

        android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter KlassenAdapter = new android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                KlassenCursor, 
                new String[] {"name"},
                new int[] {
                android.R.id.text1
                });

        setListAdapter(KlassenAdapter);

    }
```

Here my onListItemClick that don't work :(

```
 @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

     String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: getItemAtPosition, with a cursoradapter, returns a cursor ...

Comment: what do you mean by "that doesn't work"? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I think you using cursor to get data from the database.Instead of using `onListItemClick()` use `onItemClickListener()` To get the listView item details use the following code

```
yourlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

               String itemid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ColumnName");//Repeat for other values

              //Start the activity here
                Intent todayreview = new Intent(ReviewPayment.this,
                        ReviewandResend.class);
                todayreview.putExtra("iteid", itemid); 
                startActivity(todayreview);
            }
        });
```

Comment: have you got anything in onItemClick Listener?. Print the position and see weather you getting in to that.

Answer (score 0):

To use onListItemClick Add  extends ListActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
```

But i think it is better to use `onItemClick()` like Vino said